# Words for distinguishing between published/official papers and unpublished papers

Tags: word-choice

Imagine that one wanted to present a list of (a) published academic papers and theses, and (b) unpublished papers and/or essays (I'm not sure if there is a real difference between these two concepts). Which headings would make most sense to separate the two? Papers and essays? Official papers and unofficial papers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Published papers* and *Unpublished papers* seem adequate to me.

Comment: Are theses considered as *published*? In that case, it's a good suggestion.

Comment: @Speldosa: If a thesis is published it seems reasonable to call it a published paper. It depends on the practice of the particular academic institution, I suppose.

Comment: If you label the section: "Published papers and theses", you leave it ambiguous whether the thesis was actually published. You can then use "Unpublished papers and essays" as the other section heading.

Answer (score 1):

How about "releases" and "internal drafts"?

Comment: Well, doesn't "draft" imply more of an unfinished work? (The dictionary says: "A preliminary version of a piece of writing.")

Comment: Well, in that case you can call it "internal release" or "internally released papers". I got the impression that internally written papers are released once they're published, but I don't know how your organization has defined that workflow.